# Boolean search method for a binary tree

Tags: c++

I have created a function to read from a file a binary tree. The main program opens the file, reads the file using the function and then will use the boolean function to seek whether the input integer is in the binary tree using pointers.

In writing my boolean function I used essentially the same method for the read function except with the if/else arguments I had compared the value obtained there with the input value. If they are equal the function will return true and if not the function will be repeated until the end of the file. If the end of the file is reached, it will return false. **I am a beginner coder so please be patient with bad coding practice, or silly questions!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream infil;
struct node {
  int val1, val2;
  node *less, *mid, *great;
};

bool find(node*& t, int val) {
  do {
    char l, m, g;
    t = new node;
    infil >> t->val1 >> t->val2;
    infil >> l >> m >> g;
    if (l == 'Y') {
      if (t->val1 == val || t->val2 == val)
        return true;
      t->less = new node;
      t = t->less;
    } else
      t->less = NULL;
  } while (t->less != NULL || t->mid != NULL || t->great != NULL);
  return false;
}
int main(void) {
  infil.open("file.txt");
  int val;
  cin >> val;
  if (find(t, val) == true)
    // output
    return 0;
}
```

I repeated the if else with "mid" and "great". 
The file reads as
ex. 40 60 
YYY (either Y or N). The program runs, however, if I input a number that is in the file, the boolean function "find" will return false. Can I compare a pointer with an integer as I did? Or is there something else in my code that is wrong?

Comment: You should consider making this a [mcve]. There is a lot of code missing that could help figure out where this has gone wrong.

Comment: Great start, but portions of `find` are still missing. I also recommend adding in `#include` statements for the headers used. Somethimes they are important.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you! do you find this to be more helpful. Does my read function need to be included. Could the read function affect how the file is being read in a different function?

Comment: If you know you can trust the `read` function, and this is a great way to find out, skip it and build a tree by hand so that you don't need the file at all. Why does the `find` function read the file?  I'd expect the file to have already been read and stored in `t`.

Comment: Unrelated: missing semicolon at `t->less = NULL`

Comment: @user4581301 even if the file is repeated with different integers and swapping Y/N? Wouldn't those values be saved for only the last set ex. 80 90 YNY? Or without inputing those values into infil would values be changing as a form of recursion?